# Optimization counting from different index

Tags: python, pandas

I already have a solution for my problem but I am seeking for a faster way to do it.

There is a DataFrame with only two columns.

```
     In[1]: import pandas as pd

     In[2]: temp = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],'col1':[1,2,3,1,2,5],'col2':[1,2,4,1,3,4]}).set_index('id')

     In[3]: temp

     Out[3]:
          col1   col2
    id       
    a        1      1
    a        2      2
    a        3      4
    b        1      1
    b        2      3
    b        5      4
```

Now, here is my problem. I want to get the id that has the most common value of the two columns. My current solution is right below:

```
     In[4]: def count_num(table_name): return (sum(table_name.col1==table_name.col2))

     In[5]: best_value, best_ans = [0], [0]

     In[6]: for m in np.unique(temp.index):
      ...:     temp_ans = count_num(temp.loc[m])
      ...:     if temp_ans > best_value[0]:
      ...:         best_value.append(temp_ans)
      ...:         best_ans.append(m)
      ...:         best_value = best_value[1:]
      ...:         best_ans = best_ans[1:]
```

The answer for my little example is 'a'

```
     In[7]: best_ans

     Out[7]: ['a']
```

As you can find out,  I use a for loop to run the function one index a time and if there are many different index it will be time wasting.

I hope I can do the same thing without using for loop.

Thank your help!!!

Comment: In your example, `1` appears to be the most common value, but it is in both index `a` and `b` on rows 1 & 5.  It appears that you want the unique index of all values from the concatenated series with values equal to the median, but perhaps I am not understanding your question.

Comment: In my example, I want to get the id that has the most col1 == col2. The point I want to know is how can I put a function in this kind of DataFrame type without using for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `groupby`

```
In [1310]: temp.eq(temp.col1, axis='index').all(axis=1).groupby('id').sum().idxmax()
Out[1310]: 'a'
```

Alternatively,

```
In [1313]: temp.apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=1).eq(1).groupby('id').sum().idxmax()
Out[1313]: 'a'
```

Above two solutions works well for multiple columns, if you've only two columns you can

```
In [1329]: temp.col1.eq(temp.col2).groupby('id').sum().idxmax()
Out[1329]: 'a'
```

Details:

```
In [1315]: temp.eq(temp.col1, axis='index')
Out[1315]:
    col1   col2
id
a   True   True
a   True   True
a   True  False
b   True   True
b   True  False
b   True  False

In [1316]: temp.apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=1)
Out[1316]:
id
a    1
a    1
a    2
b    1
b    2
b    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is a rather small example. The true function is far more complicated. So the key for my problem is to use group by and run the function one time. Is that right?

Comment: @LeeTom - In my opinion need `True and False` Series and then `groupby` with `sum` for count `True`s, for max index value use `idxmax`

Comment: Jezael is right, this pattern can work for you larger problem, and try to vectorize your logic as much as possible for speed.

Comment: Sorry for keep asking. Can I get a version that use the function in the example. I want to know how to put a function in this kind of problem. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare columns first, then sum `True` values with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and then get index of max value by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
print ((temp.col1==temp.col2))
id
a     True
a     True
a    False
b     True
b    False
b    False
dtype: bool

print ((temp.col1==temp.col2).groupby(level='id').sum())

id
a    2.0
b    1.0
dtype: float64

print ((temp.col1==temp.col2).groupby(level='id').sum().idxmax())
a
```

What is same as:

```
print (temp.col1.eq(temp.col2).groupby(level='id').sum().idxmax())
a
```